# Subtotal (rollup?) values only from 2nd column

Tags: sql, oracle, rollup, subtotal

I'm having difficulty pinning down the proper syntax to get a total I need from Oracle 11g.  I need to produce a total based on values in column 2, independent of the values in column 1.  I've tried several types of rollup, cube, grouping sets, but I keep getting totals for each grade level (values in column 1).

Here is the 'group by' without any subtotaling:

```
... sql select statement ...
...
GROUP BY grade, inc_count
ORDER BY grade
```

which produces

```
9     714
10    550
11    445
12    296
```

And here is my goal output:

```
9     714
10    550
11    445
12    296
      2005
```

Which permutation of rollup/group sets/or something else will get me to my goal output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a UNION ALL to this `SELECT 'SUM', SUM(value) from TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

For the example you gave:

```
select grade, sum(cnt)
from t
group by cube(grade)
order by sum(cnt);
```

group by cube is "syntactic sugar" for:

```
group by grouping sets ((grade),())
```